# Method that returns a dictionary from a datatable

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have [this](https://codeshare.io/adOKpz) DAL class that contains some information in `DataTable` and there is another class named [Product](https://codeshare.io/G8J9gE).

I'm trying to write a method (inside `Product` class) that gets an integer `id` and returns a `Dictionary<int, Product>`.

Here is what I have started :

```
public Dictionary<int, Product> read(int id)
{           
    Dictionary<int, Product > d1 = new Dictionary<int, Product>();

    return d1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) \ [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

```
public Dictionary<int,string> GetProductsDict(DataTable dt)
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable()
      .ToDictionary<DataRow, int, string>(x => x.Field<int>(0),
                                x => x.Field<string>(1));
}
```

if you need an object of `Product` you can do something like that:

```
public Dictionary<int, Product> GetProductsDict(DataTable dt)
 {
     Dictionary<int, Product> d1 = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         d1.Add((int)dt.Rows[i]["id"], GetProductByID((int)dt.Rows[i]["id"]));
     }

     return d1;
 }

 public Product GetProductByID(int id)
 {
     // do stuff to extract product...
 }
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do that? translate: האם אתה מכיר דרך פשוטה יותר לעשות זאת? אגב בוא נעשה אפווט אחד לשני

Comment: האם ניתן לעשות את המטודה כך שהיא תקבל מספר מזהה ותחזיר את הדיקשונרי? כלומר הפרמטר הנוכחי בתוך הסוגריים שכתבת מקבל משתנה מטיפוס דאטא טייבל

Comment: for the rest of the viewers: you asked if there is a way that the method will get id number and return the dictionary: yes,one way to do it is declare the `Dictionary` as global and instead of passing a `datatable` pass an id number and fill the dictionary.